# How to print nested variable value of $$x as 10 ? any way is there?

Tags: groovy

How do i print 10 with x variable, i want to print 10 when i do $$x or with help of x. I want x to replce with name and name has value 10 so output should come 10.

```
def x = "name"
def name = 10

print "Sum of x + y = $$x"
```

I know this will throw error, but i want $x should replace with 'name' and it become '$name' and that print 10.

Answer (score 0):

why not use `Map` to store the key-value association?

```
def x = "name"
def valueMap = [name: 10]

print "Sum of x + y = ${valueMap[x]}"
```

prints `Sum of x + y = 10`